# Cant assign class in Vue js for list - bug or limitation?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, v-for

I am migrating a site from jquery to vue js and while in general its ending up much cleaner and simpler than the jquery version, i am hitting some obstacles which don't seem to be easily solved by Vue js.

A specific problem I am having is that I am generating a long list of ui elements. Clicking on these elements should switch the element color.
In jquery this was simply a matter of putting a listener on the class that appears on these elements and then toggle an 'active' class on the element.

In Vue its not so simple....
I am use v-for to build the list and have to create an array which holds the list of objects which define the data I need to store on these elements...something like the following...

```
               this.timeblocks = [];
               for (var j = 1; j < 25; j++) {
                    var id = 'iam'+ i + '_'+ j + '';
                    var block = {id: id, val: false,zone:'mid',  time: this.getTime(j) + ' AM'};

                    this.timeblocks.push(block);
               }
```

I now generate the list based on this data object as follows:

```
<a class="mid" v-for="(obj, index) in timeblocks" :id="obj.id" :data-value="obj.time" :class="{'active':obj.val}"  @click="toggleTime(obj,$event)"></a>
```

I would have expected that I could have just created a click event like this

```
@click="obj.val = !obj.val"
```

This would have toggled the object value from false to true which should have toggled the 'active' class. It seems to work but only once, ie for only one element and will only toggle once. I see the data changing but the css is not being applied.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Instead I currently have to use jQUery and called a toggleTime method on the click event which looks as follows:

```
   toggleTime: function(obj,event) {
        console.log('Toggle time:',obj);
        //obj.val = !obj.val;
        $("#" + event.currentTarget.id).toggleClass('active');
    },
```

I really don't want to have to use jquery and want to understand why Vue is just not working in this case.

Would appreciate any guidance or comments.
Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The selected answer below works. But I wanted to point out that the issue is something I left out of the original question.

I am actually using timeblocks as an array of arrays, being populated as follows:

```
this.timeblocks = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                this.timeblocks[i] = [];
                for (var j = 1; j < 25; j++) {
                    var id = 'iam'+ i + '_'+ j + '';
                    var block = {id: id, val: false,zone:'mid',  time: this.getTime(j) + ' AM'};

                    this.timeblocks[i].push(block);


                }
                for (var j = 1; j < 25; j++) {
                    var block = {};
                    var id = 'ipm'+ i + '_'+ j + '';
                    var block = {id: id, val: false, zone:'noon', time: this.getTime(j) + ' PM'};
                    this.timeblocks[i].push(block);

                }
            }
```

When I reference one of these (as per below) is when it does not work. Unless I implement the nextTick fix from Luis (above)

```
  <a class="mid" :id="obj.id" v-for="(obj, index) in timeblocks[1]" :data-value="obj.time" :class="{'active':obj.val}"  @click="clicktime(obj)">{{obj.id}}</a>
```

Note above I am using timeblocks[1] in the v-for and not just timeblocks. This seems to be the reason that it breaks but I am unclear why?

See here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyQmMM?editors=1011

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem is probably somewhere else in your code; [this works](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/oyXEdr?editors=1010).

Comment: You can do it this way too: https://jsfiddle.net/gn3qyu5j/

Comment: Works just fine. Something else is wrong, check your css class and if it is being overridden by something. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKPZva

Comment: I agree it should work as I see in your examples. But nothing else on my page is breaking it. It worked using the nextTick function below

Comment: Thanks again for sending samples that work. I played with your codepens to make them more similar to exactly what I was doing. One difference is that in my case I am not just using timeblocks as an array, its an array of arrays and each of my ui elements are referencing ONE of the timeblocks arrays. It seems like when I do this is when it stops working. Any idea why? see here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyQmMM?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering your list view (update) in your click method

```
<a v-show="this.showList" ...></a>

updateUI() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.showList = false;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.showList = true;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!  I am unclear why my version is not working. 
The other issue is that I have 7 of these showing on my page, which i assume is creating a lot of watchers (each of these controls has 24 elements so its 7x24 elements!). When i click on the element there is a slight delay of about 1-2 seconds before the css change is visible. Is this because of the nextTick function i am using?

Comment: Yes you're right. Maybe try re-rendering the whole list again, not each element, I mean, put the showList variable in the parent element of your list

Comment: Actually that is what I did. I didnt realize in your example you were re-rendering the element, i am re-rendering the list.